# Determine the day of the week of the given date in that month. Given the weekday of the first day of the month

Tags: python, datetime, find, dayofmonth

Day Name
Given the weekday of the first day of the month, determine the day of the week of the given date in that month.

Input
The first line is a string D.
The second line is an integer N.

Output
The output should be a string.

Explanation
In the given example, D = Monday. As the 1st of the day of the month is a Monday, it means the 7th and 14th of the month will also be Mondays (A week has 7 days). So the 16th day (N = 16) of the month will be a Tuesday.

So, the output should be Tuesday.

Sample Input 1:
Monday
16

Sample Output 1:
Tuesday

Sample Input 2:
Tuesday
17

Sample Output 2:
Thursday

Approach:

```
def determine_day_by_number(start_day: str, month_day_number: int):
    number_to_day = dict(
        [[1, 'Monday'], [2, 'Tuesday'], [3, 'Wednesday'], [4, 'Thursday'], [5, 'Friday'], [6, 'Saturday'],
         [7, 'Sunday']])
    day_to_number = dict(zip(number_to_day.values(), number_to_day.keys()))

    if start_day not in number_to_day.values():
        print('Wrong day name')
        exit()

    start_day_number = day_to_number[start_day]
    shift = get_day_shift(start_day_number, month_day_number)
    number_of_required_day = start_day_number + shift

    return number_to_day[number_of_required_day]


def get_day_shift(start_day_number: int, month_day_number: int):
    shift = month_day_number
    if start_day_number + shift > 7:
        number_of_full_weeks = shift // 7
        shift -= 7 * number_of_full_weeks
    elif start_day_number == 1:
        return start_day_number
    return shift if not start_day_number + shift > 7 else shift - 7
    


start_day = input()
month_day_number = int(input())

day = determine_day_by_number(start_day, month_day_number)
print(day)
```

INPUT:

Tuesday

1

Output should be:
Tuesday

My Output:
Wednesday

Answer (score 1):

```py
dayseq = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
inputday = input("Enter a day: ")  # monday
inputdate = int(input("Enter a date for the above day: "))  # 4
inputdayofdate = int(input("Enter a date to find day: "))  # 7      Thursday
step = 1


def loopers(currentday, step):
    if step == -1:
        if currentday == "Sunday":
            return "Saturday"
        return dayseq[dayseq.index(currentday)-1]
    elif step == 1:
        if currentday == "Saturday":
            return "Sunday"
        return dayseq[dayseq.index(currentday)+1]


if inputdayofdate < inputdate:
    step = -1

for i in range(inputdate, inputdayofdate, step):
    inputday = loopers(inputday, step)

print(inputday)
```

The above code will take 3 inputs (day date anddatetofind) and it will calculate day from the set day and date

OR

```
dayseq = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
inputday = input("Enter a day: ")  # monday
inputdayofdate = int(input("Enter a date to find day: "))  # 7      Thursday

def loopers(currentday):
    if currentday == "Saturday":
        return "Sunday"
    return dayseq[dayseq.index(currentday)+1]

for i in range(inputdayofdate -1):
    inputday = loopers(inputday)

print(inputday)
```

The above code with consider given day as 1st of a month and continue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
def determine_day_by_number(start_day: str, month_day_number: int):
    number_to_day = dict(
        [[1, 'Monday'], [2, 'Tuesday'], [3, 'Wednesday'], [4, 'Thursday'], [5, 'Friday'], [6, 'Saturday'],
         [7, 'Sunday']])
    day_to_number = dict(zip(number_to_day.values(), number_to_day.keys()))

    if start_day not in number_to_day.values():
        print('Wrong day name')
        exit()

    start_day_number = day_to_number[start_day]
    shift = get_day_shift(start_day_number, month_day_number)
    number_of_required_day = start_day_number + shift

    return number_to_day[number_of_required_day]


def get_day_shift(start_day_number: int, month_day_number: int):
    shift = month_day_number
    if start_day_number + shift > 7:
        number_of_full_weeks = shift // 7
        shift -= 7 * number_of_full_weeks + 1
    return shift if not start_day_number + shift > 7 else shift - 7


def main():
    start_day = input()
    month_day_number = int(input())

    day = determine_day_by_number(start_day, month_day_number)
    print(day)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.  Code only answers are discouraged here. Please provide a description of how your solution addresses the question to help others understand it.